# How to post a message on facebook using python?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-requests

I an newbie. I want to post a message on my facebook profile using python's requests or urllib2 library. I didn't find appropriate facebook api. Where can i find its api? How can i share a message on my profile?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use facebook-sdk for python.

> https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.org/en/latest/